# What does this mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm php newbie. I'm try and learn php from my company project, but I really dont know what is the meaning of the below.

```
<?php
$channel = $channel ;
$live_channels = $live_channels ;
$octo_link = $octo_link;
$payment_status= $payment_status ;
$is_programme_on = $is_programme_on;
$cc = $cc;
$member_profile = $member_profile ;
$nielsen_data = $nielsen_data ;
```

Comment: I've got 2 guesses: (1) Somebody needs to be fired (2) A search/replace gone bad. It happens. Either way, the "code" is pointless and you shouldn't try to gleam any knowledge from it.

Answer (score 4):

It means nothing. It's just assigning a bunch of variables to themselves.

Comment: Yes.  It makes no sense.  So you must learn somewhere else.

Comment: Oh god, is it basic on PHP? I may joined a bad company. :(

Comment: It's not even "basic on PHP" ...

Comment: It does nothing. Code is supposed to do something.

Comment: But, Good News!  This means you can SUCCEED by doing better!